# Can I see a large font size with a high resolution?

Tags: display, fonts, resolution, graphics

I'm using Macbook pro 15" and the resolution is 1680*1050.
In this resolution, characters are too small for me.
If I decrease the resolution to 1380*840, the character sizes are good for me.
Instead, I can clearly see the low quality of graphics.

Can I use high resolution while maintaining the size?
I know that I can increase only font sizes in a web browser, 
but I'm wondering if I can get the same size in high resolution
as large as when I'm in lower resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in systemwide means of adjusting the font scaling, short of running at a lower than native Resolution.  You can use the zoom tool to zoom in on a "portion" of the screen, or you can try tinkertool, which will let you change the font sizes but only for native Mac apps.

http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html